# How to set config values in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to set url field in jQuery with the config value. My code is

```
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "<%=  Config.GetInstanceConfig("WS_OtherInstanceURL")%>",
        data: "json",
     });
```

But I am not getting the URL value from the my config file.

Comment: What server side language is this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the config value for the the URL in the hidden control like this

```
<input type="hidden" id="configURLValue" value='<%=  Config.GetInstanceConfig("WS_OtherInstanceURL")%>'>
```

And in the javascript code you can access the hidden field value for the URL

```
var hiddenFieldValue = $("#configURLValue").val();
 $.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: hiddenFieldValue,
    data: "json",
 });
```

And this works!!!